# SharePoint Multiline of text field value using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the value of a SharePoint list multiline of text field using jQuery. I tried using:

```
var titleValue = $("input[Title='Title']").val(); but it returns undefined.
```

and also the following returns empty string:

```
var multiline = $("textarea[Title='multiline']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().find("Body").text();
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: are you using enhanced rich text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function PreSaveAction()
{
    //Plain text
    var value= $("textarea[title='Title']").val();
    console.log(value);
};
```

Comment: also returns undefined

Comment: ok, this other value, look at field (column) is form F12: var title = $("#ctl00_m_g_a770fe86_1f9d_4b62_929e_69a2d1180c92_ff21_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte").html();

Answer (score 1):

**For Title:**

As the Title field is required field code snippet would be:

```
var titleValue  = $("input[title='Title Required Field']").val();
```

**For Multiple lines of text:**

```
var multiline = $("textarea[title='multiline']").val();
```

Comment: Thanks Gopal, 2 example html value (<div class="ExternalClassB80F926ACB7447459E9E79351D2F6B29"><p>​value</p></div>), needed add code substring+lastindexof()

Comment: var multiline = $("textarea[title='multiline']").val(); - is undefined

Comment: Is your column type plain text or enhanced rich text ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake :))

Comment: Good for you. You learnt something ;)

Comment: I'm using a plain text column type. @Gopal

Comment: @Vusi85 try the above code and please mark it as answer if it works for you sothat it might help to others as well